# React/Material-UI: How to attach FloatingActionButton to AppBar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, floating-action-button, appbar

I read that it's possible to attach a FAB to an AppBar, but can't figure out how to do it using React/Material-UI.  All examples I can find are for Android.

Know of any example code that shows how, using React with Material-UI components, to attach a FAB to an AppBar?

Comment: I don't think there's an API for attaching a FAB to an AppBar Material-UI, I might be wrong tho. Either way, you can always do it yourself. This might get you started: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wnx2an